# Regex to find instances of a word where it is not in the path of a URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex

I would like to match instances of a word in string, as long as the word is not in a URL.

An example would be find the instances of 'hello' in the following:

```
hello this is a regex problem http://geocities.com/hello/index.html?hello! Hello how are you!
```

The simplest regex for this problem is:

```
/\bhello\b/i
```

However this returns all four instances of 'hello', including the two contained within the URL string.

I have experimented with negative look-behinds for 'http' but so far nothing has worked. Any ideas?

Comment: What is the purpose of matching `hello` here? To wrap with some tag?

Comment: Are you just counting matches?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are several solutions based on [**The Best Regex Trick Ever**](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-best-trick.html#thetrick) for 1) counting matches outside of a URL, 2) removing matches not in a URL, and 3) wrapping the matches with a tag outside of a URL:

```
s = "hello this is a regex problem http:"+"//geocities.com/hello/index.html?hello! Hello how are you!"
# Counting
p s.scan(/https?:\/\/\S*|(hello)/i).flatten.compact.count
## => 2
# Removing
p s.gsub(/(https?:\/\/\S*)|hello/i, '\1')
## => " this is a regex problem http://geocities.com/hello/index.html?hello!  how are you!"
# Wrapping with a tag
p s.gsub(/(https?:\/\/\S*)|(hello)/i) { $1 || "<span>#{$2}</span>" }
## => "<span>hello</span> this is a regex problem http://geocities.com/hello/index.html?hello! <span>Hello</span> how are you!"
```

You may wrap `hello` pattern with word boundaries if you need to match a whole word, `\bhello\b`.

See the [online Ruby demo](https://ideone.com/NWDPPw)

**Notes**

- `.scan(/https?:\/\/\S*|(hello)/i).flatten.compact.count` - matches a URL starting with `http` or `https`, or matches and captures `hello` in Group 1, `.scan` only returns captured substrings, but it also returns `nil` once the URL is matched, so `.compact` is required to remove `nil` items from the `flatten`ed array and `.count` returns the number of items in the array.
- `.gsub(/(https?:\/\/\S*)|hello/i, '\1')` matches and captures URLs into Group 1 and `hello` just matches all `hello`s outside of URLs, and the matches are replaced with `\1`, backreference to Group 1 that is an empty string when just `hello` is found.
- `s.gsub(/(https?:\/\/\S*)|(hello)/i) { $1 || "<span>#{$2}</span>" }` matches and captures URLs into Group 1 and `hello`s into Group 2. If Group 1 was matched, `$1` puts this value back into the string, else, the Group 2 is wrapped with tags and inserted back into the string.

Comment: This is perfect, Thank you so much for the link to the "Best regex trick ever" - this document is priceless :D

Comment: Thanks @Wiktor - I made a small amendment to your amazing regex to make sure it would only match full words (ie skip a partial word, such as "Helloworld" or "hellohellohello"):  `s.gsub(/(https?:\/\/\S*)|(\bhello\b)/i) { $1 || "<span>#{$2}</span>" }`

Comment: @Hanney So, you followed my advice: *You may wrap hello pattern with word boundaries if you need to match a whole word, `\bhello\b`. Note that `\b` won't work if the "word" starts or ends with special characters, `r'\b\(hello\)\b'` won't match `(hello)` in `Say (hello).` Use `(?<!\w)` / `(?!\w)` or `(?<!\S)` / `(?!\S)` then. If the `hello` is a user-defined "word", do not forget to [`Regexp.escape`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Regexp.html#method-c-escape) it.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm correct you need to get words after url. You can just use space(\s) as delimiter of your string

```
"http://geocities.com/hello/index.html?hello! Hello how are you!".scan(/\s(\w+)/i)
```

=> [["Hello"], ["how"], ["are"], ["you"]]

Or

```
 "http://geocities.com/hello/index.html?hello! Hello how are you!".scan(/\s(hello)/i)
```

=> [["Hello"]]

Comment: I'm looking for any time the word "hello" is found in the string, but only if it's not in a URL. So the return I would like is `[["hello","Hello"]]`, skipping the two instances of the word contained within the URL

Answer (score 0):

Here, we can first collect our URLs, altered by our desired words in a capturing group, with an expression similar to:

```
http[^\s]+|(hello|you)
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/0Noax3/1/)

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

#### Advice

[The fourth bird](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5424988/the-fourth-bird) advises that:

> I would go for the word boundaries and only `hello` in the group: `\bhttp\S+|\b(hello)\b`

Comment: `\bhttp\S+|\b(hello)\b` will fail if there is a second URL in the string..